# ID of item clicked - Android ContextMenu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

G'day,
 I have a ListView populated with various text values, and I want to have it that when you long press and open the context menu, you can copy the text in the ListItem you long pressed. So far I've got the context menu to pop up with the "Copy" option:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    //this was following another question but I don't know what to do with it
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    long selectedId = info.id;
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.copy:
        //used to be in a function but wasn't sure about views
        //yes I know it's depreciated but it works ;)
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        TextView clicked = (TextView)this.findViewById(???);
        clipboard.setText(clicked.getText());
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast copied = Toast.makeText(context, "Story copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        copied.show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Chirag I don't know what to put where the ??? is. If I could pass the ID of the item long-pressed, I could just do ...findViewById(id);

Answer (score 0):

Set up a variable to hold the view that gets clicked:

```
View clicked;
```

Then assign a value to it when the context menu is created on it:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    clicked = v;

    //this was following another question but I don't know what to do with it
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    long selectedId = info.id;
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}
```

And now you can use it on your final method:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId())
   {
    case R.id.copy:
        //used to be in a function but wasn't sure about views
        //yes I know it's depreciated but it works ;)
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

        clipboard.setText(clicked.getText());
        // this should work now properly.

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast copied = Toast.makeText(context, "Story copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        copied.show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: when I put this in, Eclipse says it's an error and offers to change it to item.getTitle(), however that just puts the "Copy" (title of the context menu I touched) into the clipboard, whereas I wanted the text of what was in the ListItem I originally long-pressed

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You could store the proper view in a variable when the `onCreateContextMenu` is called. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Using the above code, the `clicked.getText()` is apparently an error: "The method getText() is undefined for the type View"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your own question. The id is:

```
long selectedId = info.id;
```